# notepad++ & shell . How do I transpose on either side of the equal to '=' sign

Tags: regex, shell, unix, awk, notepad++

Wanted to see in notepad++ & shell  How do I transpose on either side of the equal to `'='` sign
Note the spaces around the `=` that are varying and indentation also changes.

```
AND TBz.C1  =   C1.x1
        AND C1.x2        =  TBv.C3
                  AND TBg.p1 =       C1.r3
    AND Tbp.sx    = C1.hx
```

O/p : all C1's should be on one side

```
    AND  C1.x1 = TBz.C1 
    AND C1.x2  = TBv.C3
    AND C1.r3  = TBg.p1 
    AND C1.hx  = Tbp.sx
```

What I tried - using `awk` everything after `=` in buffer and transpose but it does not transpose in all cases.
Looking for -  N++ Notepad++ and shell based solutions. I have to do this frequently on Red H box as well as W7.
PL take a moment to break down the steps of your regex and explain to me what's going on 
Thank You

Answer (score 2):

This awk one-liner will format your source codes and move `C1...` to the left side of `=`:

```
awk '$4~/^C1/{t=$4;$4=$2;$2=t}{$1=$1}7' file
```

Test with the given data:

```
kent$  cat f
AND TBz.C1  =   C1.x1
        AND C1.x2        =  TBv.C3
                  AND TBg.p1 =       C1.r3
    AND Tbp.sx    = C1.hx

kent$  awk '$4~/^C1/{t=$4;$4=$2;$2=t}{$1=$1}7' f
AND C1.x1 = TBz.C1
AND C1.x2 = TBv.C3
AND C1.r3 = TBg.p1
AND C1.hx = Tbp.sx
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that you start by using a plugin to align your code.

For example, you could use [Code alignment](http://codealignment.com/). This can be installed via the plugin manager. (Aligning by "=" is a built in short-cut for the plugin.)

Once you've done that, the last step is a lot more specific to your use case, so you'll need to do it manually. Your code will currently look something like:

```
AND  C1.x1 = TBz.C1
AND C1.x2  = TBv.C3
AND TBg.p1 = C1.r3
AND Tbp.sx = C1.hx
```

All you need to do now is search and replace any offending lines of code to re-order them, using capture groups. See [here](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions) for the full documentation on Notepad++ regex.

For example, you could search for:

```
AND (.*) = (C1.*)
```

And replace with:

```
AND \g2 = \g1
```

Thus switching the order.

The white-space might be slightly messed up again, in which case you could re-run the auto-aligning plugin.